# changing the format of decimal in a csv file

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, floating-point

I have a CSV file that has this format :

```html
ffsdfff llkkfk fdflmk,000,1254489632,-1256.56,,0
jlfgdgf gfgfkl kiefnf,000,2548562325,2141.6,,262.54
dfgjklf kklfgk llfsmf,000,8654344845,25.3,8654344845,-25.25
sdfsklf dfsdfg gfdggs,000,2256352124,20,2256352124,-19
```

I am struggling to get this result :

```html
ffsdfff llkkfk fdflmk,000,1254489632,-,000000000001256560,          ,+,000000000000000000
jlfgdgf gfgfkl kiefnf,000,2548562325,+,000000000002141600,          ,+,000000000000262540
dfgjklf kklfgk llfsmf,000,8654344845,+,000000000000025300,8654344845,-,000000000000025250
sdfsklf dfsdfg gfdggs,000,2256352124,+,000000000000020000,2256352124,-,000000000000019000
```

I am looking to separate the sign(+/-) from the decimal numbers. then changing the actual length of each decimal to 18.(The decimal part of the number has a max lenght of 3).

If the Fourth field is empty , I have to add 10 blank space to it.

Comment: Really? I see more changes than just separate the sign from the decimal numbers: `2141.6` ----> `000000000002141600`. What about the decimal point and the trailing zeroes?

Comment: Ohh sorry , I have added more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try with awk

```
awk '
    BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}
    function abs(v) {return v < 0 ? -v : v}
    {
        $8=abs($6*1000)
        $7=($6<0 ? "-" : "+")
        $6=$5
        $5=abs($4*1000)
        $4=($4<0 ? "-" : "+") 
        $8=sprintf("%018d", $8)
        $6=sprintf("%10s", $6)
        $5=sprintf("%018d", $5)
        print
    }' input.txt
```

you get,

```
ffsdfff llkkfk fdflmk,000,1254489632,-,000000000001256560,          ,+,000000000000000000
jlfgdgf gfgfkl kiefnf,000,2548562325,+,000000000002141600,          ,+,000000000000262540
dfgjklf kklfgk llfsmf,000,8654344845,+,000000000000025300,8654344845,-,000000000000025250
sdfsklf dfsdfg gfdggs,000,2256352124,+,000000000000020000,2256352124,-,000000000000019000
```